# How to parse json object in Value of ActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit

I have following code to call a method of my controller. The controller return response as ActionResult in form of json object.
The content of `okResult.Value` is **{ list = Count = 5, totalCount = 31 }**
How can i access the **totalCount** variable?

```
IActionResult actionResult = await _controller.List(new CancellationToken());
OkObjectResult okResult = actionResult as OkObjectResult;
var Value  = okResult.Value;
```

Thank you

Comment: `okResult.Value as MyDtoClass` is enough. `Value` is the actual object you returned  with `return Ok(thatModel)`. You don't have to serialize or deserialize anything

Answer (score 2):

All that's needed is a simple cast:

```
var invoice=(InvoiceModel)okResult.Value;
var count=invoice.TotalCount;
```

or

```
var invoice=okResult.Value as InvoiceModel;
```

The `Value` property holds the actual object passed to `OkObjectResult`'s constructor or to `return Ok(myDTO);`. It's not serialized to JSON yet.

Comment: I tested your answer but it didn't work @Panagiotis Kanavos . In other words  ``var invoice=okResult.Value as InvoiceModel;`` can not cast the **okResult.Value** . So **invoice** variable would be null

Comment: Why? What did your action's code return? If you don't return an `InvoiceModel`, you can't cast to `InvoiceModel`. If you aren't sure what `List` returns, use `(InvoiceModel)okResult.Value`. The cast error will tell you what the actual type is

Comment: @MJavadSalehi what does `_controller.List()` do? What's the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer that is working:

```
IActionResult actionResult = await _controller.List( new CancellationToken());
OkObjectResult okResult = actionResult as OkObjectResult;
var Value = okResult.Value.SerializeToJson();
InvoiceModel myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InvoiceModel>(Value);
var count = myDeserializedClass.totalCount;
```

Comment: There's no need for serialization at all. Try `okResult.Value as InvoiceModel` instead. `Value` is whatever your action returned through `return Ok(thatModel)`.

Comment: What is the *actual* return type? Are you trying to convert one type to another too? Is that why you serialize to a string then deserialize to a type?